# What cheeses have the least amount of whey in them (or not at all)?

Tags: cheese, pizza, dairy

What cheeses have the least amount of whey in them or not at all?

Answer (score 3):

When cheese is made, milk solids, in the form of curds, are separated from the whey.  The curds are then pressed to further release the whey.  Hard cheeses are pressed with greater pressure for a longer time.  So, the simple answer to your question is hard cheeses.